# Why isn't my vb.net code saving a row to my Access database? (Error)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba, database-connection

I'm trying to add a 'coupling' to my database with the following code. It give me the error "Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows."

```
Private Sub AddCoupling_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CouplingsTableAdapter.Fill(TestDatabaseDataSet.Couplings)
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonClose.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click
    Dim newCoup As DataRow = TestDatabaseDataSet.Tables("Couplings").NewRow
    newCoup.Item("Type") = ComboBoxType.Text
    newCoup.Item("Part Number") = TextPartNumber.Text
    newCoup.Item("Description") = TextDescription.Text
    newCoup.Item("Rubber Type") = ComboBoxRubberType.Text
    newCoup.Item("TKN") = Integer.Parse(TextTKN.Text)
    newCoup.Item("TKmax") = Integer.Parse(TextTKmax.Text)
    newCoup.Item("TKW") = Integer.Parse(TextTKW.Text)
    newCoup.Item("Ambient Temp") = Integer.Parse(TextTemp.Text)
    newCoup.Item("PKW") = Integer.Parse(TextPKW.Text)
    newCoup.Item("Max Speed") = Integer.Parse(TextSpeed.Text)
    Try
        TestDatabaseDataSet.Tables("Couplings").Rows.Add(newCoup)
        CouplingsTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(TestDatabaseDataSet) ' ERROR HERE '
        MessageBox.Show("Saved!")
        Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to save to database. E:" & ex.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: DataTable/DataSet are in memory snapshots of your data. When you make changes to them, you are changing the in memory information, not the database. You now need to send the data back to the server. Look at more of the properties of the DataAdapter (see help) for how this works. You can also search this site for the answers. Seems like this question comes up daily.

Comment: @Steve Up 1! I agree! It's either this or a NRE.

Comment: So, I changed it completely and tried a couple things, I feel like this SHOULD work, but I'm getting an error.